# What to do when urea fertilizer is overused for a plant?

Tags: fertilizer

I had an year old Pomegranate plant in my garden. Few days ago our garden help fertilized the plants in our garden. After four or five days the Pomegranate plant and few other plants started falling the leaves. I think our help man has over used  urea fertilizer on these plants. I particularly value this Pomegranate plant than the other plants. Can anyone suggest me a way to save this pomegranate plant which is dying of overuse of Urea fertilizer on it?

Comment: Water it down, also leaves. In past urea were used only on wet days.

Comment: I second that. Water and keep watering.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments for the question states, I started watering, I kept watering the plant. Almost every leaf fell down but after two months it started to grow back.